# Regex match double ## including any repetition of # which is not double

Tags: python, regex

How to match everything after a double hash "##" until the next double hash "##" and including any repetition of the "#" character which is not "##".
For instance the below example should return two matches, one for chapter 1 and 1.1 and the second for chapter 2.

```
## chapter 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Suspendisse mollis magna nec felis gravida, id posuere libero molestie.

### subchapter 1.1

Sed vel ipsum eget tortor maximus ultrices vitae eget dolor.

## chapter 2

Aenean pellentesque lectus quis ex tristique ultrices. Vestibulum eget purus eu ipsum vestibulum pulvinar
```

At the moment the best I found is the following regex:

```
((?!#){2}[\s\S])+
```

which however is confused when a ### or #### is found and is counted as a new chapter.

Link to regex example: https://regex101.com/r/gydtq1/1

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?ms)^##(?!#).*?(?=\n##(?!#)|\Z)', text)` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gydtq1/2).

Comment: wow thank you, can you post is as an answer and maybe explain it so I can mark as solved?

Comment: Consider using a markdown parser if you need to parse more complex patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'(?ms)^##(?!#).*?(?=\n##(?!#)|\Z)', text)
re.findall(r'^##(?!#).*?(?=\n##(?!#)|\Z)', text, re.M | re.S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gydtq1/2). *Details*:

- `(?ms)` - a `re.DOTALL` (`re.S`) and `re.MULTILINE` (`re.M`) flags
- `^` - start of a line
- `##(?!#)` - a `##` string not immediately followed with a `#`
- `.*?` - zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\n##(?!#)|\Z)` - a location immediately followed with a newline and `##` not immediately followed with a `#` or end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Matching feels "overrated" sometimes, an alternative could be

```
re.split(r'(?m)^##(?!#)', text)
```

Parts are very similar to the ones in the accepted answer:

- `(?m)` - flag for multiline (could be passed separately as a 4th argument)
- `^##(?!#)` - a `##` string at the start of a line (`^`), not immediately followed with a subsequent `#`

Caveat: the resulting list will have an entry for everything what precedes the first `##`, which is an empty string for the example.